# How to get one character at a time

Tags: c, mmap

What the outcome should look like:

```
G -- C
C -- G
T -- A
T -- A
C -- G
T -- A
T -- A
A -- T
C -- G
C -- G
C -- G
G -- C
T -- A
```

What it actually looks like:

```
GCTTCTTACCCGTGCCCCAC -- C
CTTCTTACCCGTGCCCCAC -- G
TTCTTACCCGTGCCCCAC -- A
TCTTACCCGTGCCCCAC -- A
CTTACCCGTGCCCCAC -- G
TTACCCGTGCCCCAC -- A
TACCCGTGCCCCAC -- A
ACCCGTGCCCCAC -- T
CCCGTGCCCCAC -- G
CCGTGCCCCAC -- G
CGTGCCCCAC -- G
GTGCCCCAC -- C
TGCCCCAC -- A
GCCCCAC -- C
CCCCAC -- G
CCCAC -- G
CCAC -- G
CAC -- G
AC -- T
C -- G
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    int buff = 100;

    char *ptr = mmap (NULL,buff, PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ ,MAP_PRIVATE| MAP_ANONYMOUS,0,0);
        if(ptr == MAP_FAILED){
            printf("Mapping Failed\n");
            return 1;
        }
    char *oof = mmap (NULL,buff, PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ ,MAP_PRIVATE| MAP_ANONYMOUS,0,0);
        if(oof == MAP_FAILED){
            printf("Mapping Failed\n");
            return 1;
        }
    
    int f1 = open("file.txt", O_RDWR);
    int length = read(f1,ptr,sizeof(char)*buff);
    
    for(int i = 0; i<length;i++){
        if(ptr[i] == 'A'){
            oof[i] = 'T';
        }
        if(ptr[i] == 'T'){
            oof[i] = 'A';
        }
        if(ptr[i] == 'C'){
            oof[i] = 'G';
        }
        if(ptr[i] == 'G'){
            oof[i] = 'C';
        }
        
        printf("%s -- %s\n", &ptr[i],&oof[i]);
    }

}
```

I messed around a bunch and broke it a couple of times. I feel like im just missing something and its not coming to my head.

If anyone could give me any ideas that would b great.

Comment: `%s` is for printing null-terminated strings. `ptr[i]` is not the beginning of a string. Use `%c` to print a single character.

Comment: Why do you need to use `mmap()`? Just use `char ptr[buff];`

Comment: @Goodoboi69,  Curious why `sizeof(char)` in `int length = read(f1, ptr, sizeof(char) * buff);` as `sizeof(char)` is _always_ 1?  Consider instead `int length = read(f1, ptr, sizeof ptr * buff);` to handle changes in `ptr` type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `for()` loop, just change the `printf()` statement to print chars, not strings, like so:

```
printf("%c -- %c\n", ptr[i],oof[i]);
```

`%c` -- is for chars

`%s` -- is for strings

Also, please note that the `address operator` (`&`) has been removed.  We just want the index of each array for printing chars -- not the address of the array (or the address of the array index) -- which would be useful for printing strings.

Comment: Alternatively: `printf( "%.1s -- %.1s\n", &ptr[i], &oof[i] );` :-)

Comment: @Fe2O3  wha???  No way, let me go check this, lol

Comment: @Fe2O3  Wow, [that's](https://godbolt.org/z/r85szaM57) pretty cool.  I did not know that, heheeheehee.  ( It *does* make sense though.  Just like trimming the mantissa of a float )

Comment: As one "learns" more about the language, it's good to occasionally start from the beginning again and re-read the documentation... As an "old hand at this stuff", I was startled to learn `printf( "%5.0d", n );` can replace `printf( n == 0 ? "[5xSP here]" : "%5d", n );` In other words: that `.0d` SUPPRESSES printing the digit `0`, but the field is still filled with 5 "leading spaces"... Useful to reduce clutter in a table with several/many instances of `0`... Keep learning... :-)